# Ion Android sending multipart/form-data

Tags: php, android, image, upload, android-ion

I'm trying to upload an image to my server by the code below.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Ion.with(getContext())
                    .load("postAddress/account/upload/image")
                    .setMultipartParameter("userPhoto", "xx")
                    .setMultipartFile("upload", "image/jpeg", new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg"))
                    .asJsonObject()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

However, Im getting this error.

```
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: unable to parse json
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.ion.gson.GsonParser$1.transform(GsonParser.java:55)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.ion.gson.GsonParser$1.transform(GsonParser.java:41)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.future.TransformFuture.onCompleted(TransformFuture.java:14)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.handleCallbackUnlocked(SimpleFuture.java:107)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:141)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.future.SimpleFuture.setComplete(SimpleFuture.java:128)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.parser.ByteBufferListParser$3.onCompleted(ByteBufferListParser.java:43)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.DataEmitterBase.report(DataEmitterBase.java:16)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpResponseImpl.report(AsyncHttpResponseImpl.java:92)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$4.report(AsyncHttpClient.java:424)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.FilteredDataEmitter$1.onCompleted(FilteredDataEmitter.java:24)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.DataEmitterBase.report(DataEmitterBase.java:16)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.http.filter.ContentLengthFilter.report(ContentLengthFilter.java:16)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.http.filter.ContentLengthFilter.onDataAvailable(ContentLengthFilter.java:39)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.Util.emitAllData(Util.java:23)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncNetworkSocket.onReadable(AsyncNetworkSocket.java:152)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:821)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:658)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:44)
10-26 17:58:51.864 19292-19292/tr.example W/System.err:     at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:600)
```

It looks like it does not send any data to my server.

I am using PHP slim framework on the server side

Here's the code;

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['upload_directory'] = __DIR__ . '/uploads';

$app->post('/account/upload/image', function (Request $request, Response $response) {   
    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $directory = $this->get('upload_directory');

    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['userPhoto'];
    if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
        $response->write('uploaded ' . $filename . '<br/>');
    }


});


$app->run();

?>
```

Server side implementation is an example multipart/form-data code provided by slim framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your php codes seems not response as JSON.
But your android code is expecting JSON.  It might cause json-parsing exception.

So if you want resolve it android side, change code `asJsongObject()` to `asString()`.

```
Ion.with(getContext())
                    .....
                    .asJsonObject()   //<-- before
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {

=>
Ion.with(getContext())
                ...
                .asString()  //<-- after
                .setCallback(...)
```